# Du'a to get rid of stress

Tags: practical-islam, dua

I am going through a lot of stress and anxiety I really need help is there any dua that will 100% remove my anxiety. Pls help!!

Answer (score 2):

> Those who have believed and whose hearts are assured by the remembrance of Allah . Unquestionably, by the remembrance of Allah hearts are assured." **Quran 13:28**

Everyone has stress of some sort, you ask Allah to reduce stress, be with your family, do something to distract your thoughts.

Dua is asking Allah to give you something. Allah may or may not fulfill your wish. So you ask him and also try to do happy things to get you feel refreshed.

Comment: "Allah may or may not fulfill your wish.' -- On the contrary, you wish will always be answered .. if not here then in the Hereafter as per a famous Hadith